# Getting a 404 error when sending a POST request with APIClient in Django test case

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, pytest-django

I'm writing a test case for a Django REST Framework API using the APIClient from the rest_framework.test module. I'm trying to send a POST request to the wordOftheDay/ endpoint with the provided data, but I keep getting a 404 error. It seems that the code in the except block is being executed directly when I run it using unit test command, without entering the try block at all. Interestingly, when I manually make the API call using Postman, I receive a 200 OK response.

```
def test_valid_post_request(self):
        client = APIClient()
        print(client)
        response = client.post('wordOftheDay/', self.valid_data, format='json')
        print('response',response)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        print('response.status_code',response.status_code)
        # Check if the model is created with the expected data
        self.assertTrue(WordModel.objects.filter(device_id=self.valid_data['device_id']).exists())
```

Update -
Adding the API call code here for reference.

```
def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        #d_param = request.query_params.get('d')
        d_type = request.data.get('d_type')
        o_version = request.data.get('o_version')
        d_id = request.data.get('d_id')
        w_family = request.data.get('w_family')

        if device_type is not None and os_version is not None and device_id is not None and widget_family is not None:
            device_analytics = {
                'd_type' : d_type,
                'o_version' : o_version,
                'd_id' : d_id,
                'w_family' : w_family,
            }

            self.updateDA(device_analytics, d_id, w_family)

            try:
                # #current_date = date.today()
                # current_date = '2023-10-21'
                # date_string = str(current_date)
                # valid_date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
                #
                # if valid_date:
                #
                #     word_instance = WordModel.objects.get(date=valid_date)
                #     serializer = WordSerializers(word_instance)

                word_instance = WordModel.objects.get(id=43)
                serializer = WordSerializers(word_instance)

                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

            except WordModel.DoesNotExist:
                return Response({"error": "Data for the given date does not exist"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

I have commented the original logic of the try block for reference and replaced it with a logic to return a specific record for simplicity.However, I am still receiving a 404 error with a response ("error":"Data for the given date does not exist") - when I run it through this command - python manage.py test wordOfTheDay.tests.test_wordOfTheDay.
Interestingly, when I manually make the API call using Postman, I receive a 200 OK response.

Comment: can you print response content?:
`print(response.content)`

Comment: @VladMarchenko I am getting <rest_framework.test.APIClient object at 0x7f0d39c504f0>
response b'\n<!doctype html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n  <title>Not Found</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n  <h1>Not Found</h1><p>The requested resource was not found on this server.</p>\n</body>\n</html>\n'

This is what I am getting but when I run this on postman it gives a 200 response.

Comment: Ok, can you edit your question and add code of view for *wordOftheDay* and part of test class where self.valid_data is initialized

Comment: @VladMarchenko I fixed the error for the post url part there was a prefix / missing in the url.

Comment: Ok good to know

Comment: @VladMarchenko I have updated the question with the new issue I am facing.I think while running the test command it seems that the code in the except block is being executed directly, without entering the try block at all. But it works fine when I run it using Postman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think you are missing important thing about tests, when django runs tests it creates new database, not relied to your main one, and no data form your original app will be accessible in test, so there is no object with id = 43 in there, until you create it. Basic strategy for tests is first to run tests that create some data with POST requests, and then check if data was saved properly with GET requests.

More about db:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer.
So my API is designed in such a way that it will make a post request based on the data received in the request body and return a response of word of the Day. Should I write separate tests for obtaining the response and handling POST requests in my API, given that the endpoint serves two distinct purposes?

Comment: Hi. if this self.updateDA is making request to some another endpoint in your app and it changes something in your db, you can make some GET request in your tests and check if self.updateDA worked properly

Comment: the self.updateDA is not making a request to another endpoint. The purpose of that function is to add a new entry in the db with data from device analytics = {}.